# Disable/enable an input field

Tags: jscript

Using this sample code, I am trying to enable/disable the field "arrdatfrom".  However, once this text field has been DISABLED, i cannot get it to be re-ENABLED.   The function below gets executed when the user clicks a "Refresh" button.  I have built this little demo just to prove that   I have tried many ways to do this.  Any ideas?

```
function showBooking() {
    var d = new Date()
    formvals.arrdatefrom    = document.getElementById("arrdatfrom").value
    formvals.arrdatethru    = document.getElementById("arrdatthru").value
    formvals.depdatefrom    = document.getElementById("depdatfrom").value
    formvals.depdatethru    = document.getElementById("depdatthru").value
    formvals.bookname       = document.getElementById("bookname").value
    formvals.peakroomfrom   = document.getElementById("peakroomfrom").value
    formvals.peakroomthru   = document.getElementById("peakroomthru").value
    formvals.peakattendfrom = document.getElementById("peakattendfrom").value
    formvals.peakattendthru = document.getElementById("peakattendthru").value

    alert (' ngs.hta  ready to enable')
    document.getElementById("arrdatfrom").enabled = 'true'

    alert ('ngs.hta in showBooking!!  disable.  ')
    document.getElementById("arrdatfrom").disabled = 'true'
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no property `.enabled`. To re-enable a disabled element, set `.disabled = false`.